# The local variable which is used in return statement doesn't convert to r-value implicitly to match the conversion operator

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, move-semantics, standards-compliance

In the example snippet code below, the local variable which is used in `return` statement doesn't convert to r-value implicitly to match the *conversion operator*. However for *move constructor* it works.

I want to know whether it is a standard behavior or a bug. And if it is a standard behavior, what is the reason?

I tested it in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.8.3) in **'permissive-'** mode and it produced a compiler error. But in **'permissive'** mode, it was OK.

```
#include <string>

class X
{
    std::string m_str;
public:
    X() = default;
    X(X&& that)
    {
        m_str = std::move(that.m_str);
    }
    operator std::string() &&
    {
        return std::move(m_str);
    }
};

X f()
{
    X x;
    return x;
}

std::string g()
{
    X x;
    return x; // Conformance mode: Yes (/permissive-) ==> error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'X' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
    //return std::move(x); // OK
    // return X{}; // OK
}

int main()
{
    f();
    g();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From [a little test](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf1fc271fcb5730b), it appears that clang is more strict than gcc. I myself would expect an error for `return x;` since `x` is an lvalue in this context. (But of course, I'm not the standard.)

Comment: It appears like the C++11 standard only makes allowances for implicit move with a constructor (oversight?), but the current draft allows it for a conversion operator (and Clang and cppreference are just behind the times).

Comment: @TrebledJ Why do you expect an error for `return x;` in `g()` but not in `f()`? What is the difference? I expect both of them to be correct; because after `return` statement they are not needed any more and it is more efficient to be moved from.

Comment: The `return x;` in `f()` is different since copy-elision may take place, optimising away copy/move. However, in `g()`, `x` is an lvalue (whereas `std::move(x)` and `X{}` are rvalues) and no `operator std::string() &` was defined, so my intuition was that it would error out. Like I said, my intuition is not necessarily correct though.

Comment: The standard says that in `return x;` where the type of `x` matches the return type of the function and `x` is a local variable, the overload resolution is performed as if `x` were an rvalue, thus allowing to find move constructors. `g()` doesn't match that special case, since the return type doesn't match that of `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `f` works under the [C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (link is to a close-enough draft) is this clause

`[class.copy]/32`

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source
> object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to
> select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. ...

And the "criteri[on] for elision of a copy operation" that is relevant in this case is

`[class.copy]/31.1`

> - in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value

This works for `f`, since `x` in `return x` is the "name of a non-volatile automatic object ... with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type"; that type is `X`. This does not work for `g`, since the return type `std::string` is not the type `X` of the object named by `x`.

I think it might be important to understand *why* this rule is here in the first place. This rule isn't *really* about implicitly moving function-local variables into function return values, even though that's what it literally says. It's about making NRVO possible. Consider what you would have to write for `f` without these rules:

```
X f() {
    X x;
    return std::move(x);
}
```

But then NVRO cannot apply, since you aren't returning a variable; you're returning the result of a function call! So the clause `[class.copy]/32` is about making your code

```
X f() {
    X x;
    return x;
}
```

*syntactically* legal, while the semantics as described by the clause (using a move constructor) are to be ignored (assuming your implementation isn't too stupid) because we're *actually* just going to do NRVO, which doesn't call anything.

You see that, really, `[class.copy]/32` doesn't *have* to work for `g`. Its purpose in `f` is to make it possible to execute *zero* copy/move constructors. But `g` *has* to execute the conversion operator; there's no other sensible way for the language to pull out a `std::string` when you give it an `X`. So NVRO cannot apply in `g`, so there's no need to write `return x;`, so you can just write

```
std::string g() {
    X x;
    return std::move(x);
}
```

and not be worried that will cause a missed optimization.

We see that the C++11 rule `[class.copy]/32` is designed so that it affects the minimal portion of the cases possible. It applies to those cases where'd we'd *like* NVRO but don't have a copy constructor, and makes NVRO possible by telling us to pretend we'll call the move constructor. But when actually *writing* code, that means it's a mind-twister of a rule to remember: "to minimize copies/moves, if the return type is the same as the type of the variable, `return the_variable;`, and otherwise `return std::move(the_variable)`." That's why the C++20 standard completely rephrases `[class.copy]/32` into

[`[class.copy.elision]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3)

> An *implicitly movable entity* is a variable of automatic storage duration that is either a non-volatile object or an rvalue reference to a non-volatile object type. In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation is first considered before attempting a copy operation:
>
> - If the *expression* in a `return` (`[stmt.return]`) or `co_­return` (`[stmt.return.coroutine]`) statement is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an implicitly movable entity declared in the body or *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression*, or
> - ...
>
> overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy or the `return_­value` overload to call is first performed as if the expression or operand were an rvalue. ...

This *does not* require that the return type be the same as the variable's type for an implicit move; it can be summed up as the conceptually simpler rule "returning a variable tries to move, and then tries to copy". That leads to the conceptually simpler principle "When returning a variable from a function, just `return the_variable;` and it will do the right thing". (Of course, *none* of GCC, Clang, *or* MSVC [seem to have gotten the memo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLgGZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEuABlIAHVAsLqtHqGJuY%2BfgF0tvZORq7unF5KKmp0DATMxATBxqacFsmYqoHpmQTRji5unooZWTmh%2BbVlFbHxngCUiqgGxMgcAORSZnbIhlgA1OJmOuoKBMSYzEbT2OIeAILrG/PEBqoTABpTAOyymxOXRxAdU2YAIhNYVMwGrATT5xtXE6jebswiMQJnYCDcppIAGxSSGnaQTRYEXq0CYeT6ne7bcQnTFmL7bUETKjg7FfH7HAAen22P0RyImVLxWJxWM2hKMzDsJLONKu83QIBQPQIdx00x0RJJM3FEMk4gArDpaFI5UzNtj7gMuqwQAN5QNSKYBh4DahdWKZHIJgoen1MBCzJwDQRdSaOl0ANYgMzygB0AA4TpxOABOEOJDzcbj%2BnjyoS67gGo0m0hmgYGhQgLwu41a0hwWAwRBCozePDsMgUCBoUvl6pjETAYMeLxUcsENyZiDOV0G5x2TIAT11TtINaMWgIAHlaKxh7nSFgOaJ2L3F3hFsUAG6YTMLzAUooGDsjg2g5Rr1h4ZzEId6LCn0gLPBGU9dGj0JhsDg8fggSRCI2KByHIQjXpmkBdH8qS0HuAC0/LTPcEiWjIkgpoUxQaBAVgNHkljaK0VQJOE/gwXhgi%2BGRgREXE1ScIoyhFDBpT1PouSCJhLF1OUdiVHRJHzGUFEMUJWS0e0nBdDavT9Fw2q6vqhprmmFL%2BpCcGQtwEwNqIEzBr6HiGRMEC4IQJAOgxEx6LWFYOpItwWrIMjOr27qkF6ZhmIZkgnOGIbcPKJweJCYbxgMiakK%2B8peMmpq6hmWZPm5%2BZFhASA1mWFbkJQmV1u4TYeABbbvJ2lA9gu/a0EOj7jpOM5zmuS6NquC74Juag7nuKYHkeJ4DKO546guV43neGCDKOz6vgNeYfowLCrr%2BAgMcIojAah8ijRBNypt4MHwYhDwoc50joRmTFYaYOHaCJBE2HxbT0aRkRBOxjQvTBEnPVxJQ8Xdv1pDx32Cf9734WJvExMR8ndLJP4KXqSYqbqakaVpEzAMgyD6UZkgmWZQKWaQ1moLZbiWY5IEuclubuQgSxYO4u3DZF0WxSj6aKElOZup63reSFIXcCcWlRpwfkhuFZjIwuaauXTqXwOlJZZW4OXVmTavuFuyDeN4AD6W6hgbkj%2BgbFJaaQJUdsQXYVSmVU1bNY5kxO9ANfOKbNSugzexuzF4F1a69cgx6TWe9AXiN163sQg73hHT7EC%2Bb7W3QC3flwvACBYa1iNTW3gfAUH7YEe4APT8htp3CB28wXSkgSaLd4OCFYIOURE5FtwxVGvZ3omXdxwm94xTdAy0j0w6JYMhBDwPTwJsMyXasPDUpcWpqjGNGAousTMbIa%2BmbBP4ETwxWTZ2sOmYVObQrfMed6nCGZCMbymYkjyvK%2BRmIG4VIpb3ltzbMblEaSFlimEBvMtRdB3HbZu3AgA%3D). That has to be some kind of record...)

Comment: It is strange that when I change `int` to `string` in your linked code, gcc and msvc (not c++latest) can compile the code: https://godbolt.org/z/GezKoc